# Using Jquery Show() with the 'scale' effect to only animate the width doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scale, show

I am trying to use the 'scale' effect from jQuery UI to show() and hide() a div with an image in it.

My issue comes up because I only want to scale the div in the horizontal direction.

I followed the info on this page to do that:  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale

My code looks like this:

```
$('#myDiv').hide('scale', {direction: 'horizontal'};
```

and

```
$('#myDiv').show('scale', {direction: 'horizontal'};
```

While the hide() works as expected, the show() command scales the div both horizontally and vertically despite the 'horizontal' setting.  I'm guessing there is something different about my div after it's hidden which is causing the direction setting to not work right.

Could this be a bug?

Comment: Provide scaling with direction.
Ex :  { percent: 200, direction: 'horizontal' }

Comment: Aby, as you can see in my code, I am using direction. It's not working.  I tried adding the percent setting, it made no difference.

Comment: Is that inside a click handler ?

Comment: No, it just runs in the code after a delay(). Right now I'm just testing the animation effect to see if I can get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this accomplish what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/eSE2n/1/

Comment: Stuart, thanks for the sample but no it does not. I need the item to scale horizontally from the center that's why I chose the 'scale' effect specifically.  I'm trying to create the effect of a playing card turning over by shrinking its back side in the horizontal direction to the center and then expanding the div in the horizontal from the center with a new img. I haven't changed images yet because the effect itself does not look right.